# RabbitMQ on prem clustered with an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, on-premises-instances

I am running rabbitMQ on a server at my office. I want to have a failover instance running in aws ec2 but am having trouble clustering them. I am able to connect to both the on prem and ec2 instances of rabbitMq that I installed from docker. Both instances have a DNS domain name linked to them. I am starting the instance on ec2 with this command:
`docker run -d --hostname rabbit-01 --name rabbit-01 -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=root -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=toor -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3-management`

I think I need to pass the `RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE` to it, however if I do, the docker container doesn't seem to start, and gives no error :(

I would love to be able to do this without having to vpn the ec2 intance into my local network.

Is this possible? Am I going about this in the wrong way? Has anyone managed to get this setup working before?

Thank you very much!

Comment: trying adding the option --network mynet to the command and see what happens